# Pausing video if currentTime >= 2

Tags: javascript, html, video, addeventlistener

I'd like to pause a video when currentTime is >=2 but I have a problem.
When you click on white div, video changes and I want that video to pause at 2 sec. But as you can see on the fiddle, first video pauses at 2 seconds too and I don't want that. I want my eventhandler function to work only with the second video not the first one.

**HTML**

```
<video src="videos/loop.webm" id="video" width="100%" autoplay> 
</video>
```

**JS**

```
    //This code tracks currentTime
        $("#video").on(
            "timeupdate", 
            function(event){
              onTrackedVideoFrame(this.currentTime);
            });
         });

        function onTrackedVideoFrame(currentTime){
            $("#current").text(currentTime);
         }

         video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
               if (this.currentTime >= 2.000 && this.currentTime <= 8.000) {
                     this.pause();
                }
             }, false);
    //This code tracks currentTime


   //this code changes video source
    var videoSource = new Array();
    videoSource[0]='videos/loop.webm';
    videoSource[1]='videos/fullcut.webm';
    var videoCount = videoSource.length;      

        function videoPlay(videoNum)
        {
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.setAttribute("src",videoSource[videoNum]);
    video.load();
    video.play();
        }
    //this code changes video source
```

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fKfgp/22/

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to set the timeupdate listener to after you set the new source.

```
$("#video").on(
    "timeupdate", 
    function(event){
      onTrackedVideoFrame(this.currentTime);
});

function onTrackedVideoFrame(currentTime){
    $("#current").text(currentTime);
 }

var videoSource = new Array();
videoSource[0]='http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
videoSource[1]='http://www.tools4movies.com/trailers/1012/Kill%20Bill%20Vol.3.mp4';
var videoCount = videoSource.length;      

function videoPlay(videoNum)
{
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.setAttribute("src",videoSource[videoNum]);
    video.load();
    video.play();
    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
        if (this.currentTime >= 2.000 && this.currentTime <= 8.000){
          this.pause();
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know it'd be that easy. Thanks a lot Cory!